# Vertically align div with a left floatting parent

Tags: html, css

I need to center a div vertically.
The particularity is that the parent is *floating to left* and *has no defined height*...

I have the following:

```css
#parent {
    background:bisque;
    float: left; /*not to change*/
}
#parent div {
    display:inline-block;/*not to change*/
}
#foo {
    background:aliceblue;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#bar { /*not to change*/
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background:lightgreen;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo">Child Foo</div>
    <div id="bar">Child Bar</div>
</div>
```

1) How to vertically center `Foo` ?
2) Why does the padding of `Bar` affected the `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are your answers:

1. Add `vertical-align` to `bar` to center `foo`. Bigger items take correct vertical alignment.
2. Both are `inline-block;` so the default `vertical-align` is for the `baseline`.

**Snippet**

```css
#parent {
  background:bisque;
  float: left; /*not to change*/
}
#parent div {
  display:inline-block;/*not to change*/
}
#foo {
  background:aliceblue;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#bar { /*not to change*/
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  background:lightgreen;
  padding:10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="foo">Child Foo</div>
  <div id="bar">Child Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: normally the bar is not to change... is crazy that we manipulate one element to change another that is even not its parent! I don't want to change the bar vertical align, I am happy how "bar" is represented...

Comment: @Serge But basically we are changing the default one, which is not middle. When the bigger one, that is not supposed to be changed, is in a wrong position, what would you do?

Comment: If to suppose the child size is defined by the inner text, I am not always able to know the "bigger one"

Comment: If I have no height but the synamic text inside the div, the size of a div is unpredictable a priori... so we need to set the vertical-align to every of the child divs available...